# Координаты items из выделенного участка графической сцены

Tags: pyqt5

Почему-то при print(item.x(), item.y()) в консоль выводится(выводятся) координаты равные 0.0 0.0. Может выводятся координаты не относительно сцены, а относительно координат самих итемов?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView,
                             QMainWindow, QApplication, QGraphicsRectItem)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRectF, QPointF, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTransform


class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsScene, self).__init__(QRectF(-500, -500, 1000, 1000), parent)

        self._start = QPointF()
        self._current_rect_item = None
        self.rects = []
        k = 0
        for i in range(50):
            for j in range(50):
                self.addRect(15 * i + 10, 15 * j + 10, 10, 10)
                k += 1

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):

        clickecRect = self.itemAt(event.scenePos(), QTransform())
        if clickecRect is not None:
            clickecRect.setBrush(Qt.green)

        if self.itemAt(event.scenePos(), QTransform()) is None:
            self._current_rect_item = QGraphicsRectItem()
            self.addItem(self._current_rect_item)
            self._start = event.scenePos()
        super(GraphicsScene, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self._current_rect_item is not None:
            r = QRectF(self._start, event.scenePos()).normalized()
            self._current_rect_item.setRect(r)
        super(GraphicsScene, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        self._start.x()
        self._start.y()
        event.scenePos().x() - self._start.x()
        event.scenePos().y() - self._start.y()
        selected_items = self.items(r)

        for rect in self.rects:
            rect.setBrush(Qt.white)

        self.rects.clear()

        selected_items = selected_items[1:]

        for item in selected_items:
            item.setBrush(Qt.green)
            self.rects.append(item)
            print(item.x(), item.y())

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super(GraphicsScene, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self.removeItem(self._current_rect_item)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        scene = GraphicsScene(self)
        view = QGraphicsView(scene, self)
        view.setSceneRect(0, 0, 1800, 2000)
        view.setGeometry(0, 0, 1200, 800)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 600)
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение проблемы. Оказывается, у полученных объектов методом items() из выделенного участка, необходимо вызывать метод rect(), который возвращает объект. У этого объекта можно вызвать методы x(), y() и получить координаты. Тоже самое касается и объекта, полученного методом itemAt().

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView,
                             QMainWindow, QApplication, QGraphicsRectItem)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRectF, QPointF, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTransform


class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsScene, self).__init__(QRectF(-500, -500, 1000, 1000), parent)

        self._start = QPointF()
        self._current_rect_item = None
        self.rects = []
        k = 0
        for i in range(50):
            for j in range(50):
                rect = self.addRect(15 * i + 10, 15 * j + 10, 10, 10)
                k += 1

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        clickecRect = self.itemAt(event.scenePos(), QTransform())
        if clickecRect is not None:
            clickecRect.setBrush(Qt.green)
            rect = clickecRect.rect()
            print(rect.x(), rect.y())

        if self.itemAt(event.scenePos(), QTransform()) is None:
            self._current_rect_item = QGraphicsRectItem()
            self.addItem(self._current_rect_item)
            self._start = event.scenePos()
        super(GraphicsScene, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self._current_rect_item is not None:
            r = QRectF(self._start, event.scenePos()).normalized()
            self._current_rect_item.setRect(r)
        super(GraphicsScene, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        self._start.x()
        self._start.y()
        event.scenePos().x() - self._start.x()
        event.scenePos().y() - self._start.y()
        selected_items = self.items(r)

        for rect in self.rects:
            rect.setBrush(Qt.white)

        self.rects.clear()

        selected_items = selected_items[1:]

        for item in selected_items:
            item.setBrush(Qt.green)
            self.rects.append(item)
            rect = item.rect()
            print(rect.x(), rect.y())

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super(GraphicsScene, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        self.removeItem(self._current_rect_item)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        scene = GraphicsScene(self)
        view = QGraphicsView(scene, self)
        view.setSceneRect(0, 0, 1800, 2000)
        view.setGeometry(0, 0, 1200, 800)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 600)
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```